# python 2.7 Use inside one function a method of a class, when class instance is in another function

Tags: python-2.7, class, methods, instance

This is a an example of the code:

`module1.py` is imported in the main.
In modul1.py, there is an `init()` function that creates classes from a previous imported library, and then, other functions uses this instance of the class, and the methods of that class.

```
ERROR: global name name1  not defined
```

**module1.py:**

```
from lib import class1, classs2

def init():
    name1.class1()


def function():
    name1.class1method1()
```

**main.py:**

```
import module1
init()

function()
```

I need some help, thanks

Comment: you simply call a non existing name (variable, module or whatever) `name1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be getting confused between creating an object from a class definition and accessing the methods of the class.  You are getting a *not defined error* because you have yet to define `name1`.

With the following adjustments, your code would work:

**module1.py:**

```
from lib import class1, classs2

def Init():
    global name1
    name1 = class1()


def function():
    name1.class1method1()
```

**main.py:**

```
import module1
module1.Init()

module1.function()
```

That being said global variables are a bad idea, so the above code is for demonstration purposes only, not for actual use.